# How to escape an equals sign in param element's value attribute?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, escaping, flash

I have an embed tag that will be used to store a SWF object. I've been following this documentation here

https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html

I need to create a parameter with a name equal to `FlashVars`.

I need to store an API token in the value attribute. The problem is there is an equals sign in the token itself.

My token is

```
var token = "GABVZgTs_____2R2cHlzNHd5ZXg3Z2M0OXdoaDY3aHdrbo80onzX6aHp2ytZg17l7bE="

<object data="http://www.rdio.com/api/swf/">
  <param name=FlashVars
         value="token=GABVZgTs_____2R2cHlzNHd5ZXg3Z2M0OXdoaDY3aHdrbo80onzX6aHp2ytZg17l7bE="></param>
</object>
```

The result of the value attribute is to be embedded inside quotes. Then inside the quotes you have the syntax

```
key=value
```

but the value itself has an equals sign in it. Am I supposed to embed the value inside the value inside quotation marks?

Here are the API instructions

> The API SWF must be embedded from http://www.rdio.com/api/swf/ with
>   the following flashvars arguments:
>
> `playbackToken`: a valid playback token, retrieved from the
>   getPlaybackToken Web Service API method
>
> `domain`: the domain that the SWF
>   will be embedded in
>
> `listener`" the name of a JS object to receive
>   callbacks
>
> `enableLogging`: Optional, provides debug logging when set to 1
>   The easiest way to embed the SWF is to use the SWFObject library.
>
> Status callbacks will be called on whatever object was passed in as
>   the callback parameter. For example if foo was supplied then the ready
>   callback will be called as window.foo.ready().
>
> Methods can be called directly on the embed object — the  or
>    tag’s DOM node. Since Flash itself defines some methods all
>   methods are prefixed with rdio_.
>
> To call the play method on an API SWF with ID bar you could call:

I've also been using this source

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_param.asp

Comment: Does it not work?  I'm not sure if Flash will ignore an `=` if there is no preceding ampersand.

Comment: From the documentation, I get that `=` is used as a separator between keys and values. I'm not sure because I've never worked with flash before

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is have you tried it yet?  Because my guess is that it should work.   URL variables are split on the ampersand.  Then the first `=` found is used to differentiate the name from the value.  So as long as there isn't an ampersand between your two equals, it it theory should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is also good to URL encode your parameters, in this case, it will work fine AS-IS.

URL variables are split on the `&` (ampersand). Then the first `=` found is used to differentiate the name/key from the value. So as long as there isn't an ampersand between your two equals, it will be fine.

Indeed, I tested your exact token value, and it worked no problem.

The best practice though is to use javascript or your server script to URL encode the **values** before putting them in FlashVars.

eg:   JS:

```
var token = "GABVZgTs_____2R2cHlzNHd5ZXg3Z2M0OXdoaDY3aHdrbo80onzX6aHp2ytZg17l7bE=";
var flashVarToken = encodeURIComponent(token);
var paramNode = "<param name=\"FlashVars\" value=\"token=" + flashVarToken + "\"></param>";
```

Then in AS3 decode the value.

```
var token:String = unescape(this.loaderInfo.parameters.token);
```

Using this approach, you can have as many ampersands and equals and spaces etc that you want in the value without messing it up.

Answer (score 0):

- Save the value in a variable.
- do a `replace("=", "\\=").`
- Then your value will contain the escape character '\'.

Hopefully I answered your question.